Differences between Banach and analytic $p$-adic local Langlands correspondence
I have been trying to understand the categorical $p$-adic local Langlands paper [EGH 23] and I have a question regarding the differences between the Banach and analytic case of the conjectured correspondence. Why is it the case that for the Banach case, the stack of "etale" $(\phi, \Gamma)$-modules over the family of rings $A_{K, A}$ is considered, whereas for the analytic case, the rigid analytic Emerton Gee stack is defined as the moduli stack of $(\phi, \Gamma)$- modules over the Robba ring without any etale or slope 0 condition? Is there a deep reason here, or is it just a matter of convenience? Thank you in advance.
